# Compilation Error in while making changes in Mat-dialog-box in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9, mat-dialog

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined

core.js:4197 ERROR Error: The pipe 'translate' could not be found!

these two errors pop out in the console whenever I change my code inside the mat-dialog box and compile my code and after that my dialog also does not open

But If I stop my Angular server and rerun it.., the changes are working fine

Any solutions or if anybody has faced a scenario like this?

Comment: Are you using JIT? I have same kind of problems sometimes with mat dialog when I use JIT mode. So are you running aot=false?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change Detection is not working properly. Please try using ChangDetectionRef.

Ex: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detectchanges